# Docker Login for AWS ECR failing with "Cannot connect to the Docker deamon..."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I'm having trouble getting started with ECR because the login command generated by

```
aws ecr get-login
```

returns:

```
 Warning: '-e' is deprecated, it will be removed soon. See usage.
 Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Unfortunately, the documentation for ECR doesn't acknowledge this as possible issue. Has anyone here experienced this before and if so what did you do to fix it? For reference I've setup AWS CLI with an IAM user that has policies for full EC2/ECR permissions attached. I've also created a permissions statement on the ECR registry that allows my IAM user full rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker service is not running on your machine.
You will be able to login/connect to ECR, only when the docker process is running.

Comment: You were right. I had to create a new one with `docker-machine create -d virtualbox default`. Thanks for answering my stupid question!

Comment: can you clarify more...? what machine? docker run hello-world works for me -- but the docker command returned from awscli gives me the cannot connect message Bill had.

Comment: @badgley I don't know what the machine command is, but when I ran the `docker login` command as root it worked, I'm not sure why.

Comment: @badgley my issue was that I hadn't actually finished setting up docker. I'd installed it, via the toolbox on OS X, but I hadn't created a VM to run it on so there was no docker daemon for the command to connect to.

Answer (score 2):

As i updgraded Docker to version 17.06.2-ce, this deprecation notice moved to be an error :

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e
See 'docker login --help'.
```

The cause is the "aws ecr get-login" command returing an invalid parameter ("-e none"). Before this docker version, it was a warning / depreciation error, now docker failed with a return code of 125.

To prevent this, I log on ECR with this command :

```
$> $(aws ecr get-login | sed -e "s/-e none//g")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `--no-include-email`, like:

```
$ aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1
```